# Validate that only one value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two relevant columns. I'll call them EID and MID. They are not unique.

In theory, if the data is set up correctly, there will be many records for each EID and every one of those records should have the same MID.

There are situations where someone may manually update data incorrectly and I need to be able to quickly identify if there is a second MID for any EID.

Ideally, I'd have a query that returns how many MIDs for each EID, but only showing results where there is more than 1 MID.  Below is what I'd like the results to look like.

```
EID      Count of Distinct MID values
200345   2
304334   3
```

I've tried several different forms of queries, but I can't seem to figure out how to reach this result. We're on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following using [`COUNT` with `DISTINCT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql#a-using-count-and-distinct) and [`HAVING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql):

```
SELECT EID, COUNT(DISTINCT MID)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY EID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT MID) > 1
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9655e5452f7ab7f22a4cee89e890b1cc)